# Delete row if column equals 0 (mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

hello I am building a shopping cart and I ran into an issue. Currently when someone adds an item they fill out the quantity and click add to cart. That item is inserted into the cart table with this command

```
INSERT INTO cart(item_id, cart_id, quantity)
VALUES(?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    quantity = quantity + ${quantity};
```

ok so that works fine if I have an item in the cart that already exists it adds on to the quantity with the new quantity given.

So my issue if someone types in 0 quantity for example I want that item to be deleted from the cart. right now I have

```
if (Number(quantity) === 0)
{
    const del = `DELETE FROM cart WHERE cart_id=? AND item_id=?`
    const values = [cartId, itemId];

    connection.query(del, values, (err, results, feilds) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send('deleted item from cart');
    });
}
else
{
    const query = `INSERT INTO cart(item_id, cart_id, quantity)
                   VALUES(?,?,?)
                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                   quantity = quantity + ${quantity}`;

    const values = [itemId, cartId, quantity];

    connection.query(query, values, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
    });
}
```

That works fine but im wondering is there a way to do this with just mysql? For example

```
INSERT INTO cart(item_id, cart_id, quantity)
VALUES('the_items_id', 'the_cart_id', quantity)
IF quantity = 0 
DELETE FROM cart WHERE card_id='the_cart_id' AND item_id='the_items_id'
```

Just so you know cart_id is the users id associated with the cart stored in a cookie. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it in a single SQL query.

Comment: Ok so the way I have would it be the accepted answer?

Comment: BTW, you should use `quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity)` rather than substituting `${quantity}` into the SQL.

Comment: What do you mean sorry? quantity is a variable and im using ${} to escape the quotes

Comment: I know what you're doing. You shouldn't do that. In `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you can refer to the value of a column that would have been inserted using `VALUES(columnName)`, so you don't need to substitute a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Ok I dont fully understand but it works. Is that only for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?  Sorry I am really new to mysql

Comment: Yes, it's only for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: I see what you mean here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You won't actually be able to do it in one query, However you will be able to do this in one transactions.

Basically you can just

```
START TRANSACTION;

If(Cart exists)
   IF(Item exists in cart)
      IF(quatitiy <= 0) -> delete item
      Else(add item to cart)

COMMIT;
```

But basically, to to do what you are looking for in one query wont be possible. 
But to implement that logic can be done using one transaction.

Read up here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html 
May help.

Cheers